# How can I keep the date format from a VLookup returned value?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, vlookup

I have a sheet whit mixed format data (dates, double, strings, etc.).
I search the value (my_index) in the lookup_range and I want to retrieve the data to change with it a cell in other sheet.  It works fine, but when the value returned by VLookup is a date and I set it to the other sheet it looses its date format.

```
Dim lookup_range As Range
Dim my_index, my_value As Variant

my_value = Application.VLookup(my_index, lookup_range, num_col, False)
Sheets(3).Cells(num_row, last_col_s1 + num_col - 1).Value = my_value
```

So, when the data in the lookup_range is `02/05/2014` the data showed at sheet-3 looks like `41761`.

I need to keep the original data format of the data in the lookup_range.

Comment: I don't have time to do the code for this right now, but if you use the "Match" function instead of the VLookup function, then you use the num_col to get the actual cell that you are trying to copy.  Then if you use "newcell.numberformat = oldcell.numberformat" it will maintain the formatting.

Comment: @OpiesDad Thanks, I'll try it with Match method to locate the cell and then copy the value and the format.

Answer (score 2):

`VLOOKUP` doesn't care about the formatting of the data it's returning - it returns *data*, not *formats*.

The only way to ensure the same format as the source, is to copy/paste that format, either manually or programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Excel Formula :

```
=TEXT(VLOOKUP(Lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,0),"dd-mm-yyyy")
```

VBA :

```
Sub vlookup_code()

    Dim table_rng As Range

    'FOR THE TIME BEING GIVING A LOOKUP VALUE
    look_up_value = "sekar"

    'SETTING THE TABLE ARRAY RANGE
    Set table_rng = Sheet1.Range("C3").CurrentRegion

    'SINCE VLOOKUP WILL GIVE AN ERROR, IF THE LOOKUP VALUE IS NOT PRESENT
    'TO HANDLE THIS ERROR, WE USE THE ISERROR STATEMENT
    If IsError(Application.vlookup(look_up_value, table_rng, 2, 0)) = False Then

        vlook_value = WorksheetFunction.vlookup(look_up_value, table_rng, 2, False)

        'CHANGING THE VLOOKUP VALUE FORMAT TO DATE FORMAT
        date_format = WorksheetFunction.Text(vlook_value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Sheets(3).Cells(num_row, last_col_s1 + num_col - 1).Value = cdate(my_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and simply reformatted the VLOOKUP cell to also be in date-time format. That fixed my issue. I am not sure how date-time gets translated into a number, but it does.

Comment: It _is_ a number.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue. After vlookup, change the format to "ShortDate" format. This will give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Office 2016.

Once data copied to the cell. Select the column which needs to be in date format. Right click->format cells, go to Number tab and select date from the drop-down and choose the required date format, data will be converted to date format.